# how to pass new parameter in loopback login?

Tags: loopback

i have a problem in login with looback i wanna add 3rd paramter
this is default code of loopback

```
<pre>
 User.login({username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}, function (err, token) {
     console.log(token.id);
   });</pre>
```

i wanna pass a new parameter like

```
<pre>User.login({username: 'foo', password: 'bar',is_deleted:'0'}, function (err, token) {
     console.log(token.id);
   });</pre>
```

i also try pass third parameter is_deleted=0 but it is not worked in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can do login by following combination:

1. username & password
2. email & password

So if you want to inject some logic before login then you can use operation hooks, do some stuff and perform login with any of above mentioned combination.

Sample code :

```
extentedUser.beforeRemote('login', function (context, user, next) {
      // Do some operation or validation here
      next();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to do with that third parameter? if you want to perform any logic before login method, you can create a new remote api and after performing that logic call default login api inside it.

something like :

model.newAPi = function(param1, param2, param3){

//use param3 to perform logic

app.models.User.login(param1, param2);
}